# what are the best practices to separate resource file from the ASP.NET web project?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application project which contains few resource file. i am planning to create another one project for Mobile where i should be able to use the same resource files.

so can you suggest me some best practices to separate the  resource files.

Let me know if you need any clarifications for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you can find an answer for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140628/sharing-asp-net-resource-files-between-web-applications). In my opinion it is the best solution in this case

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one...but I would create a separate new project, MyProject.Localisation, and then place all the resx files in there.  Marking them as Embedded Resource, Do not copy.  Then reference that project from what ever project needs the resources.