# ASP.NET inline expression Resources cannot find key

Tags: asp.net, resx

in my solution I have a project `Web`, which contains all the pages. I have resource file in project `ProjectResources` which is named MyResources.resx (and another one MyResources.de.resx)

On all my pages in the HTML code I'm using the inline expression Resource to obtain the strings from the resources like this:

```
 ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources: ProjectResources.MyResources, PasswordConfirmationFailed %>"
```

When I open the page, I have the parse error

```
Parser Error Message: The resource object with key 'PasswordConfirmationFailed' was not found.
```

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdts6s2d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I have found this example:

```
Text="<%$ Resources: Financial, Currency %>" />
```

And a comment below:

> This code reads the following value from a resource file named Financial.resx in the App_GlobalResources directory.

I guess it cannot find my resource file somehow. I'm pretty sure this is very stupid but I cannot resolve it...

p:s: I've made the changes using the expression with regex on all pages simulationesly and it's not working for every page, not just for one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140628/sharing-asp-net-resource-files-between-web-applications)

You cannot use the Resource expression when referencing .resx file in another assembly.