# Use embedded resource in asp.net inline code

Tags: asp.net, embedded-resource

I created a project with my resource files in. Each resx file has Build Action "Embedded Resource", Custum Tool "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" and Custum Tool Namespace "MyDomain.Resources".

My web project has asp.net files. This project references the project with the resources.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHome" runat="server" Text='<%= MyDomain.Resources.Layout.Dashboard %>' />
```

In the web browser I see <%= MyDomain.Resources.Layout.Dashboard %> instead of the text in the resource.
Layout.resx is a resourcefile with Dashboard a item in it.

in the resx file:

```
<data name="Dashboard" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Dashboard</value>
</data>
```

I tries several inline asp tags, with no result.

Comment: Can you show some more of your markup. What's the filetype, what's the webserver that's giving you this? What happens if you use the Response.Write in a different section of your markup?

Comment: Filetype resource is resx and webpage is asp.net. When put in the page, not in the control, the text from the resource file is displayed.

Comment: solution found in the following post:
[Sharing asp.net resource files between web applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140628/sharing-asp-net-resource-files-between-web-applications)